# How to deserialize a dynamic property in a well defined model?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net, deserialization

I have a web api method defined as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post(Input model)
{
    ...
}
```

With Input model like this:

```
public class Input
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public object Extra { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do is pass a valid JSON object as the extra parameter like the following example with jQuery:

```
$.post(
    'http://localhost/api/myController',
    { 
        id: 'someId',               
        extra: { 
            tags: ['a', 'b'],
            anotherValue: 'hello',
            oneMore: { 
                foo: 'bar'
            }
        }
    });
```

*Id* comes correctly into my model.Id property. However, the *extra* property comes as an {object} and since I don't know whats in there I cannot deserialize it in any way.

I tried making it *dynamic* and/or casting it to dynamic/ExpandoObject/Dictionary without success. I know that I can probably make it work if I just receive a raw HttpRequestMessage and handle it myself. Hoever I would rather not do it and rely in all validations that .NET has in place.

Is it possible?

Thanks

**EDIT 1:** After testing some more alternatives I found that the *extra* property does not have any real value and it's just initialized as a *new object()*. Looks like the default model binder implementation does not deal with dynamic JSON (at least not like this) and simply call the default constructor of the model property that it cannot deals with.

Comment: @SanjaMelnichuk I didn't understand how this can help me. I do not have a JSON string that I can use to pass to the deserializer. All I have is the model object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining your property as `object` should work or if you want to be explicit you give your `Extra` property the type `JObject`.

However the problem is with `$.post` request. In order to post complex data to a web.api method and allow the model binding you need to do two things:

- set the content type to 'application/json'
- and send the data as JSON with calling `JSON.stringify` on it

But with `$.post` you cannot specify the content type so you need to use `$.ajax`:

So the following call should post the data to your action:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/api/myController',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(
    { 
        id: 'someId',               
        extra: { 
            tags: ['a', 'b'],
            anotherValue: 'hello',
            oneMore: { 
                foo: 'bar'
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: It worked @nemesv! Thanks :) One more thing, though: the caller needs to stringify the data when not doing it is way easier. Is there another when where the caller does not have to do that? I can provide a JS client to my consumers, but if they want to build their own it would be much simpler to not use the stringify. Thanks again!

Comment: @tucaz In general it is enough if the client sends a valid JSON payload. However if the client is implemented with JQuery because the `$.ajax` method call will: [the Data is converted to a query string, if not already a string.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) So you need to call `JSON.stringify` otherwise `$.ajax` url encodes your data. But if you have other clients then won't necessary need to call `JSON.stringify`